# I had a signature verification error with migration from Helium to Solana

Tags: blockchain, web3js, solana-web3js, anchor-solana, helium-api

everyone.
As you know, the migration from Helium to Solana is finished in April 18th.
I tried to move hotspots from Helium Network to Solana using this reference.

https://docs.helium.com/solana/rewardable-entites

But after execute the last part, I got error like this.

```
Error: An error occured: Signature verification failed
    at /home/ubuntu/Documents/Solana/Helium-Solana-MigrationCode/src/6-Single-Asset-Claiming-Reward.ts:55:23
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/home/ubuntu/Documents/Solana/Helium-Solana-MigrationCode/src/6-Single-Asset-Claiming-Reward.ts:30:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Error: Signature verification failed
    at Transaction.serialize (/home/ubuntu/Documents/Solana/Helium-Solana-MigrationCode/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/transaction/legacy.ts:775:13)
    at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (/home/ubuntu/Documents/Solana/Helium-Solana-MigrationCode/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:157:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I just tried to search several reference to this error, but couldn't.
I used this url https://rpc.helius.xyz/?api-key=e10cecdb-6be6-4c56-ac23-075ac22482e3 for rpc.
If succeed, the hotspots should be migrated to Solana network.